# Externalize the values in config files in vert.x and EKS

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables, amazon-eks, vert.x

I use to work on spring boot and when i need to externalize the config values. I genrally create a application.yml

```
SUD:
  BASEPATH: ${SUD_SERVICE_BASE_PATH:https://origin-sud.com}
  MCS_BASEPATH: ${SUD_SERVICE_MCS_BASE_PATH:https://sud.com/}
  MCS_TOKEN: ${SUD_SERVICE_MCS_TOKEN:a2341b8b-4ca5-4513-8c52-gf267bihbh}
  MCS_SUBSCRIPTION_ENDPOINT: ${SUD_SERVICE_MCS_SUBSCRIPTION_ENDPOINT:/v1/manag}
  HOST: ${SUD_SERVICE_HOST:sud.com}
```

Now The values like

```
SUD_SERVICE_BASE_PATH
SUD_SERVICE_MCS_BASE_PATH
SUD_SERVICE_MCS_TOKEN
SUD_SERVICE_MCS_SUBSCRIPTION_ENDPOINT
SUD_SERVICE_HOST
```

Are getting data from EKS config map. If the values are not present, we get to the default values.

```
https://origin-sud.com
https://sud.com
```

To access it in the spring boot code. We do the below operation. It get the data from EKS config if present or default to default values.
@GetMapping("${SUD.MCS_SUBSCRIPTION_ENDPOINT}")

Now i want to do that same in vert.x.
I have read vert.c blog but i couldn't find a way to do it.

The only way i found out it to get the values like

```
String host = System.getenv.getOrDefault("SUD_SERVICE_BASE_PATH", https://origin-sud.com);
String port = System.getenv.getOrDefault("SUD_SERVICE_MCS_BASE_PATH", https://sud.com/);
```

I want to do something similar to spring boot , instead of calling the System.getenv.getOrDefault. I want to do it in config.

Appreciate the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x Core does not provide such a solution.

You need to add the [Vert.x Config](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/#_available_configuration_stores) module, which is able to merge values coming from different sources (system properties, environment variables, config files... and more)

Comment: Can you tell me the best way to read values from EKS config map?

Comment: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/#_kubernetes_configmap_store